# blank page after signing in through webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I tried signing in twitter through the webview ! I typed in the username and password

"Redirecting you back to the application " was shown then a blank page few seconds later 
(same for google/facebook accounts)

as u can see below my code doesn't include much! I only have a webview!

**Mainactivity.java**

```
 package com.example.myapplication;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebSettings;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView mywebview;
public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebview = findViewById((R.id.webView));
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mywebview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT);
    mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.websitename.com");
    mywebview.setWebViewClient((new WebViewClient()));

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mywebview.canGoBack()) {
        mywebview.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


}


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try enabling domStorage:
mywebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)

Comment: it didn't work unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webframe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```